# React Native IOS Archive not working with react native new version

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, ipa

I am working on a project since 1 year and doing important updates regularly. Last time before 3 days i archive and generate a IPA but after loading screen, app is crashing. But when i run the app it is working fine and everything is working as before.

Check below link i am attaching the video of IOS.

http://cidev.in/demo.mp4

Comment: What is the exception thrown in the crash dump?

Comment: That's big issue i am not getting any crashes..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to run the app in release mode?
on Xcode
Product --> Scheme --> Edit-Scheme --> Build configuration "Release"

It could be a number of different things, but a good first step is to get it in a production environment.

Answer (score 0):

please go to Xcode Product --> Scheme --> Edit-Scheme --> Build configuration "Release and then go product and go to archieve